# The floating point function of Chopping. Absolute error and Relative error.

Tags: floating-point

Consider a number $(x)_\beta$ :
$$x = \pm 0.d_1d_2 \ldots d_pd_{p+1}d_{p+2} \ldots \times \beta^E$$
The function $chop(x)$ considers only the first $p$ digits ignoring digits from $(p+1)$th to infinite. So the machine number $\tilde{x}$ is the number obtained from the above function:
$$\tilde{x} = chop(x) = \pm0.d_1d_2 \ldots d_p \times \beta^E$$

For the **Absolute Error** $e_A$ we have :
\begin{split}
e_A(chop(x)) 
& =  |x - chop(x)|  \\
& =  0.\underbrace{00 \ldots 0}_{p \text{ zeros} }d_{p+1}d_{p+2} \ldots \times \beta^E \\
& =  0.d_{p+1}d_{p+2}\ldots \times \beta^{E-p}  <  \beta^{E-p}
\end{split}

For the **Relative Error** $e_R$ we have that:

\begin{split}
|x| 
& \ge 0.d_1 \times \beta^{E}  \\ 
& =  d_1 \times \beta^{E-1}  \ge   \beta^{E-1}
\end{split}

since $d_1 \ne 0$ we have that:
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
e_R(chop(x)) & = & \left | \frac{x - chop(x)}{x} \right | & < & \frac{\beta^{E-p}}{\beta^{E-1}}
& = & \beta^{1-p}
\end{array}
$$

We can see that the *Relative Error*, (conversely from the *Absolute Error*), doesn't depend from the size of the number, but only from he number of digits of the mantissa. Therefore, if we have many digits in the mantissa, the *Relative Error* will be smaller.

---

This is what I want to ask:

In the last part, I don't understand how to obtain that inequality:

$$\begin{align}{}
\ldots = \left | \frac{x - chop(x)}{x} \right |  <  \frac{\beta^{E-p}}{\beta^{E-1}} = \ldots
\end{align}$$

I know that:

- $|x-chop(x)| < \beta^{E-p}$
- $|x| \ge \beta^{E-1}$

it seems that we have an implication like this, (using a not fully suitable notation) :
$$$$\begin{align}{}
\frac{\left | x - chop(x) \right | < \beta^{E-p}}{|x| \ge \beta^{E-1}} 
\Longrightarrow \left | \frac{x - chop(x)}{x} \right |  <  \frac{\beta^{E-p}}{\beta^{E-1}}
\end{align}$$$$

Is there any algebraic-property applied here?

Please, Can you give me any suggestions?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $|x| \geq \beta^{E - 1}$ we have upper bound for $\frac{1}{|x|}$ (assuming everything is positive)
$$
\frac{1}{|x|} \leq \frac{1}{\beta^{E - 1}} \quad (1)
$$
we can now apply this and the 
$$|x - chop(x)| < \beta^{E-p}\quad (2)$$ to
$$  \left | \frac{x - chop(x)}{x} \right | = |x - chop(x)|\cdot \frac{1}{|x|} $$
first we use (1) getting
$$ |x - chop(x)|\cdot \frac{1}{|x|} \leq  |x - chop(x)|\cdot \frac{1}{\beta^{E - 1}}$$
then we use (2)
to get the upper bound you are asking about
$$ |x - chop(x)|\cdot \frac{1}{|x|} < \beta^{E-p}\cdot \frac{1}{\beta^{E - 1}}. $$

Now the main question I guess is how do we get
$$ |x| \geq \beta^{E - 1} \rightarrow \frac{1}{|x|} \leq \frac{1}{\beta^{E - 1}}.$$
The most general rule I think is that when you apply decreasing function to an inequality you have to flip the inequality sign. You are probably familiar with this for multiplication by $-1$ that is apply $f(x) = -1x$ to both sides of inequality. 
For 
$$ a \leq b $$
we have
$$ -a \geq -b.$$
In this case you are applying $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ to both sides of the inequality which is decreasing function so we have
$$ a < b \rightarrow \frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b}. $$
To demonstrate with numbers 
$$ 0.5 < 2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{.5} = 2 > \frac{1}{2}. $$
You can also easily see this if you plot the $f$ for positive numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I understand what property you have applied, but still I have problems to apply in the case. Can you add any intermediate passages on how to get the upper bound? And also, above, in the beginning we had $\le$, and then we had $<$, why?

Comment: and also, from $$\frac{1}{|x|} \le \frac{1}{\beta^{E-1}}, \quad|x-chop(x)| < \beta^{E-p}$$
what we do? we go to multiply the same side? It's unclear, can you explain better this part? thanks.

Comment: You can multiply two inequalities (in the same direction), just like equalities, if $a < b$ and $c < d$ then $ab < cd$, to demonstrate with numbers $2 < 3$ and $4 < 5$ yields $8 < 15$. 
The strict inequality for upper bound comes from strict inequality in $|x - chop(x)| < \beta^{E-p}$. again to ilustrate if you have $2 \leq 2$ and $4 < 5$ you get $8 < 10$. I have added intermediate steps, which do not use this, but in the future it is easier to work with inequalities like this.